# nginx HttpSecureLinkModule php example

Tags: php, nginx

I have this configuration but I just can't make it work, Im having a hard time trying to figure it out..

I'm Trying get a fileserver under nginx using the HttpSecureLinkModule by making it with an expiration time..

Here's what I have in nginx:

```
 location /files/ {
    secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;
    secure_link_md5 "secret$uri$arg_e";

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    if ($secure_link = "") {
            return 403;
    }
    if ($secure_link = 0) {
            return 410;
    }
}
```

And now In the remote server hiddenfile.php

```
<?php
$file="file/99/240182409124019248407098227489702";
$secret_word = "secret";
$uri_prefix = "http://domain.com/";
$time = time()+600;
$md5 = base64_encode(md5($secret_word.$file.$time, true));
$md5 = strtr($md5, '+/', '-_');
$md5 = str_replace('=', '', $md5);
$url= $uri_prefix.$file.'?st='.$md5.'&e='.$time;

?>
```

The result is something like this:
http://domain.com/file/99/240182409124019248407098227489702?st=94ASFASF7SAF8AF9S898&e=38573287583

All I'm getting in the nginx's acceess.log is a 403 error..

Can anyone provide a simple example on how to do this? I've tried several things with no luck..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `$uri` in nginx starts with slash and in php you miss it

Comment: yeah it was just like that... the "/" was missing at the beginning of the $file variable in php..Thank you!!!

Comment: @AlexeyTen Excuse me, i use this code and work fine but when try with files that have symbols like `()` its return 403, can you help me, please?

Comment: @aidin if you have a question create a new topic

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer for this question by Alexey Ten..

```
$uri in nginx starts with slash and in php you miss it –  Alexey Ten 14 hours ago
```